# Screen blackout and "No Signal" on screen, PC still runs with music. Fans on, LED on, Safe Mode works

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, gpu, external-display

I have a problem with my PC. I have had it for a year without any problems, but recently it's started to have some weird issues:

- Sometimes, the PC is up and running with music still playing in the background, but then the screen flashes for half a second and "No signal" appears on the screen. The GPU LED remains on, the CPU's as well; all fans stay on.
- I installed the latest GTX driver (seemed to have less problems than the previous)
- I re-installed Windows and the problem seems to happen less but still happens
- I have run memtest, 2 passes, and found no problem with the RAM
- When I boot into Safe Mode, there is no issue at all, the screen stays on all the time, no freeze or anything. (Perfect, but can't run games because Safe Mode doesn't use the GPU.)

**Here are the specs:**

- Motherboard: ASUS P6T-SE
- GPU: ASUS GTX 760
- PSU: EVGA NEX 750G (750 watt)
- RAM: DDR3 7GB total
- SSD: 128 GB Samsung
- HDD: 500 GB Hitachi
- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
- Temperature: GPU and CPU idle at 33 C, when in use up to 55 C

CPU-Z results:

[image]

The screen blacks out randomly, regardless of temperature or load.

Does my GPU need to be replaced, or is something else going on?

Comment: have you tried switching the output method/port?

Answer (score 0):

Check power options and see when your screen is set to go to sleep. Depending on the player, windows wont recognize it as "active" and will shut your screen off. THis is especially true with google play music and other web based music.

Answer (score 0):

Such strange freezes and sporadi crashes can happen because of the `Command Rate (CR)` of `1`. Go to the BIOS/firmware and change the value of [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings) to 2 in the advanced memory options.